# Sustituir la letra “o” por “x”

Tags: javascript

tengo el siguiente problema:
En **JavaScript** ingreso un texto con **prompt();** y por ejemplo el usuario ingresa “hola mundo” entonces lo que estoy intentando hacer es que quede de la siguiente manera “hxla mundxx”

Como ven sustituir las “o” por la “x” pero se van incrementando conforme van apareciendo letras “o”.
Espero que me puedan apoyar

Gracias

Comment: Puedes poner lo que intentaste? Donde te esta dando problemas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto deberia hacer lo que pides

```
// Caracter a reemplazar
var reemplazar = "o";
// Cadena reemplazadora (se modifica en la ejecución para añadir mas)
var reemplazo = "x";
// Caracter de reemplazo
var charReemplazo = "x";
// Cadena a reemplazar
var str = "hola mundo";
// Variable para la longitud de la cadena (tambien es variable)
var longitudCadena = str.length;

// Bucle para reemplazar linea a linea
for (i = 0; i < longitudCadena ; i++) {
    // Obtenemos el caracter de la posición i
    var res = str.charAt(i);
    // Si el caracter es el buscado entramos en el if
    if(res == reemplazar){
       // Obtenemos la longitud de lo que va insertar
       var longReemplazo = reemplazo.lenght;
       // Reemplazamos con substrings (desconzoco si hay otra opcion con una funcion directa)
       str = str.substring(0,i) + reemplazo + str.substring(i+longReemplazo );
       // Aumentamos la longitud de la cadena con los caracteres de mas incluidos
       longitudCadena = longitudCadena + longReemplazo-1;
       // Aumentamos la cadena de reemplazo
       reemplazo = reemplazo + charReemplazo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si logro entender seria algo como esto:

```
var str = "Hola mundo";
var res = str.replace("o", "x");
```

Si es así, te recomiendo leer un poco sobre manejo y/o operadores de string.

Comment: Estas preguntas sin código de avance no se deben responder

Comment: con ese codigo solo reemplaza la primera "o", hay que hacer algo ocmo esto para que las cambie todas:

`var res = str.replace(/o/g, "x");`